# scikit kmeans not accurate cost \ inertia

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to get the k-means cost (`inertia` in scikit kmeans).
Just to remind:

The cost is the sum of squared distanctes from each point to the nearest cluster.

I get a strange difference between the cost calc of scikit('inertia'),

and my own trivial way for computing the cost

Please see the following example:

```
p = np.random.rand(1000000,2)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
a = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(p)
print a.inertia_ , "****"

means = a.cluster_centers_
s = 0
for x in p:
    best = float("inf")
    for y in means:
        if np.linalg.norm(x-y)**2 < best:
            best = np.linalg.norm(x-y)**2
    s += best
print s, "*****"
```

Where for my run the output is:

```
66178.4232156 ****
66173.7928716 *****
```

Where on my own dataset, the result is more significant(20% difference).

 Is this a bug in scikit's implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - it does not seem to be a bug (but for sure ugly inconsistency). Why is that? You need to take a closer look into what is the code actually doing. For this general purpose it calls the cython code from `_k_means.pyx`

(lines 577-578)

```
    inertia = _k_means._assign_labels_array(
        X, x_squared_norms, centers, labels, distances=distances)
```

and what it does is essentialy exactly your code, but... using **doubles** in C. So maybe it is just a numerical issue? Let us test your code but now, with clear clusters structure (thus there are no points which might be assigned to many centers - depending on numerical accuracy).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances

p = np.random.rand(1000000,2)
p[:p.shape[0]/2, :] += 100 #I move half of points far away

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
a = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(p) #changed to two clusters
print a.inertia_ , "****"

means = a.cluster_centers_
s = 0
for x in p:
    best = float("inf")
    for y in means:
        d = (x-y).T.dot(x-y)
        if d < best:
            best = d
    s += best
print s, "*****"
```

results

```
166805.190832 ****
166805.190946 *****
```

makes sense. Thus the problem is with existance of samples "near the boundary" which might be assigned to multiple clusters depending on arithmetic accuracy. Unftunately I was not able to trace exactly where the difference comes from.

**The funny thing** is that there is actually an **inconsistency** coming from the fact, that `inertia_` field is filled with **Cython** code, and `.score` calls **NumPy** one. Thus if you call

```
print -a.score(p)
```

you will get exactly **your inertia**.

Comment: Yes but this problems becomes important when testing it on some other datasets where the difference is 20%. What do you think about that?

Comment: I posted the issue on their github, as this is for sure something requiring closer lookup. I suggest you use `-a.score(X)` for now, as it is at least consistent with the rest of your code (which I assume is written in python).

Comment: please send me a link to this

Comment: It seems that with sklearn 0.17 the problem vanishes https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6156#issuecomment-171312478